# AdHoc provisioning - what's the easiest way to add a few more devices to an existing project that's still in development?

Tags: iphone, provisioning, adhoc

I have a project that I've been working on for a while.  It is a standard Xcode/Objective-C iPhone app.  I created the provisioning file for my device and a couple others.  Now I would like to add a few people as testers.

Do I need to download and install a new provisioning file?

Do I need to change settings in Xcode?

What's the easiest way to do all this?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate Question :http://stackoverflow.com/a/11789914/846372

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will need to create, download, and distribute a new .mobileprovision file, and reconfigure your project to use it:

1. In the iPhone Developer Program portal, add the new [devices](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/devices/index.action).
2. Edit your existing ad hoc [distribution provisioning profile](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/provisioningprofiles/viewDistributionProfiles.action) and check the boxes to add the new devices to the profile.
3. Refresh the Distribution tab for a few seconds until the profile status changes from Pending to Active.
4. Download the modified .mobileprovision file, and install it by dragging it onto the XCode or iTunes icon in your dock.
5. In XCode, right click on your target, do Get Info -> Build, and change your Configuration to Distribution.
6. Change the setting under Code Signing Identity -> Any iPhone OS Device to use your new provisioning profile.  Pay close attention to the dates in the list and make sure you use the most recent copy.
7. Distribute the new .mobileprovision file to your users with your next ad hoc build.

Comment: Will this make the earlier test version stop working on the devices? Lets say I add new devices and create new provisioning file and neu build. And I distribute this new build with the new provisioning file only to the just added people. Will the other ones with the older provisioning file be able to use the application?

Comment: Testers included in the provisioning profile for an older build will still be able to install and use the older version of the app until that provisioning profile expires.  If you issue a new build that excludes a tester from the new provisioning profile, he'll be unable to install the new build, but he'll still be authorized to run the older build.

Answer (score 7):

You **don't have to recompile your project again**. In fact you don't even have to open XCode.

All you have to do is create a new mobileprovision file and distribute it with the existing app.

Your end users have to download and install the new mobileprovision file and app, by this order.

**Here is a [step-by-step](http://esrimobile.blogspot.pt/2012/12/on-my-previous-post-wrote-on-how-to.html).**

Answer (score 1):

Unless the other people are iphone developers with their own development profile, you will need to make an ad-hoc profile and build.

It is pretty easy... just follow the instructions in the developer portal.  All you have to do is clone your release configuration, change a few lines and add a plist entitlements file (all provided in the instructions).  Then just send the tester the build and the provisioning profile you create with their device-id included and they should be able to drag it into itunes to install.

If they are developers and people you trust, just give them the code and have them change the Bundle Identifier to whatever is in their development domain.