# Why is my UDID listed under "Anonymous Devices"?

Tags: ios, testflight

I am registered as a Developer with TestFlight. I added the UDID for my iPad to TestFlight and see it linked to my account.

I built an .IPA for my iOS app, against an ad-hoc distribution profile which includes a single UDID - my iPad.

When I uploaded my build to TestFlight, the permissions page lists my UDID under "anonymous permissions" - it is identical to the UDID TestFlight has on file:

[image]

And here it is in the Apple dev-center:

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure what I might have done wrong here? Is there anything else that has to match?

Comment: You could try to download the AdHoc provisioning profile and upload that to Testflight. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try following approaches:

1. Connect the device to a user account: Check out [this guide](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829600-how-do-i-connect-my-device-to-my-account-)
2. It may also be in anonymous devices because it is not added to the iOS certificate, try to update it with the device UDID: check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528768/adhoc-provisioning-whats-the-easiest-way-to-add-a-few-more-devices-to-an-exis)

Comment: Thing is, it correctly lists me (with my device) under "team-mates in the provisioning profile" - see top of first image. I sent a notification and installed the app just fine. It's just the weird thing it also lists my device UDID as anonymous when clearly it _knows_ it's my device!

Comment: @John see option 2, check if the device is known by the profile you use for testflight

Comment: If you mean the adhoc distribution profile then it is - in bottom 2 images you see "Jdx iPad" belongs to adhoc profile, and that "Jdx iPad" has UDID listed. If you meant something else (there are so many profiles and certificates!) could you clarify?

Comment: @John I once had an expired profile that was being shown as normal working profile. Try to delete and generate your profiles again. It's the only cause I can thing of, otherwise I'm out of ideas.

Comment: also, have you upload your provisioning profile to testflight?

Answer (score 0):

Login your Test-flight account using your iPad(device) it will be solved your issue.("Device in your provisioning profile that are not own by testflight users")

Comment: I already did that. That's how TestFlight knows about my iPad - see top image, top-right "iPad 2 Wifi"